# Revert commit using reset head

Tags: git, github

How come on one repsitory when I try:
`git reset head~1`, this removes the latest commit.
While on a different repository (github), it gives me the following error message:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'head~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Comment: can you share your output of `git reflog`?

Comment: I would guess you only have one commit in your 'other' repo.

Comment: @ckruczek no there are several commits on develop

Comment: @AshishRanjan updated the begin post

Comment: reflog says you only have one commit.

Comment: Note that MacOS and Windows default to doing case-folding, so that the names `HEAD`, `head`, and even `hEaD` and `heAD` and so on, all refer to the same thing. Linux systems don't. This will create problems for you if you ever have a branch named `master` and a *different* branch named `Master`, for instance: the Linux folks will handle it no problem, but your Windows system won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

`HEAD`, not `head`.

Or just `@`:

```
git reset @~1
```